# Identificar o dia da semana de uma determinada data

Tags: python, python-3.x

Uma das questões de uma tarefa da faculdade está dando trabalho para toda a turma, até agora ninguém conseguiu responder a questão 4. Um amigo meu tentou com esse código, mas não funciona direito, pois dependendo das entradas, o mês sai 13, 14, 19 e inúmeros outros meses inexistentes. Alguém poderia me dar uma ajuda?
PS: Precisa ser em python 3.

> **Questão**: Você terá umas férias maravilhosas que começam no dia 3, quarta-feira. Você retornará das sua férias depois de 137 noites (Uauu!). Escreva um programa que pede o dia do mês e o dia da semana em que você irá viajar e pede ainda o número de dias que você ficará de férias e imprime o dia da semana que você voltará.

Código:

```
def questao4(m,s,f):
    f = f+m
    t = f%30
    rs = t%7
    return print("Mês =", t,"Dia da semana =", rs)
questao4(9,3,1)
```

Comment: Eu entendo que a pergunta é sobre calculo, provavelmente para ensinar algo, mas devo dizer que considerando possivelmente fuso-horarios, variações de dias para cada mês e algo mais talvez, suponho humildemente que não vai ter precisão fazer só na base do calculo, teria que usar alguma lib que trabalhe com datas e timezone.

Comment: Supondo que eu fosse fazer baseando na timezone do Brasil, teria como dar alguma dica de como fazer isso?

Comment: Timezone do Brasil ou não varia conforme ou pode variar, veja mesmo o presidente poderia ter tirado o horario de verão de SP, mas não o fez, manteve, o que já afetaria a aplicação, uma lib assim vai trabalhar baseada no horario da maquina e a maquina (seja Windows, seja Linux) baixa a hora atualizada e assim vc conseguiria "a precisão" (aproximadamente, com perda de segundos talvez, ou se o usuário mudar algo na maquina, como a hora). O que eu quero dizer é que se a tarefa da faculdade tiver a intenção de ensinar matematica+programação a lib e fuso horarios não vão resolver em nada, pois ...

Comment: ... o foco da pergunta da tarefa é aprender matematica com python, agora se não é esse o objetivo do teu professor então sim uma LIB do Python que trabalhe com timezone e etc seria o caminho ideal, eu só posso te dar "dicas" ou até formular uma sugestão se tiver a certeza do que o teu professor tiver explicado a intenção disto.

Comment: O professor não prioriza que aprendamos matemática, e sim que sejamos capazes de codificar oque é pedido.

Comment: Entendo John, mas muitos exercicios podem ter algum fundamento para serem aplicados assim, de qualquer forma espero que então o uso das libs `date` e `timedelta` resolvam pra ti.

Comment: Então só pra terminar, eu **suponho** que informar o dia da semana na pergunta é um baita indicio que o problema é de matemática, pois se não for então informar o dia da semana seria irrelevante em um uso com libs/apis de data, basta o mês e o dia dele que o resto da pra resolver na "API" mesmo.

Comment: O "pior" é que realmente não é para focar na matemática, e sim para resolver oque se é pedido não importa se usando matemática mesmo, ou só no raciocínio. Agradeço a ajuda x)

Answer (score 3):

Essa questão pode ser resolvida facilmente com a biblioteca [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html), criando um objeto `date` que representa a data e um `timedelta` que representa o intervalo de tempo a ser considerado.

```
from datetime import date, timedelta

DIAS = [
    'Segunda-feira',
    'Terça-feira',
    'Quarta-feira',
    'Quinta-Feira',
    'Sexta-feira',
    'Sábado',
    'Domingo'
]

inicio = date(year=2018, month=4, day=26)
ferias = timedelta(days=137)
final = inicio + ferias

print(DIAS[final.weekday()])  # Segunda-feira
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/AquamarineGrandNaturaldocs) | [Ideone](https://ideone.com/07sSTo) | [GitHub GIST](https://gist.github.com/48d739e7ef64ab75b82fe2f35557957a)</sup>

Mas, como o foco do exercício provavelmente é a matemática, basta você pensar nas operações a serem feitas. Se eu entro de férias dia 3, quarta-feira, e fico nela por 137 noites, significa que ficarei 19 semanas completas mais 4 dias. Ao final das 19 semanas, saberei que será novamente uma quarta-feira, então basta eu verificar qual dia da semana será 4 dias após (mas como é um exercício de faculdade, deixo a implementação desta lógica contigo).

Comment: Muito bom, só temo que o exercício/tarefa tenha com intenção ensinar matemática+programação, como expliquei melhor nos comentários acima, de qualquer forma o código esta muito bom e irá ajudar muita gente, espero que esse seja o caminho para o AP também +1

Comment: A intenção nem é voltada pra matemática, e sim para garantir que conseguimos codificar oque está sendo pedido não importa como. Agradeço muito a ajuda x)

Answer (score 0):

```
x = input("Quantos dias voce ficara de ferias? ")
duracao_ferias = int(x)


y = input("Digite o dia do mes que voce ira viajar: ")
dia_viagem = int(y)

dia_retorno = duracao_ferias + dia_viagem
if (dia_retorno > 30):
    dia_retorno = (duracao_ferias + dia_viagem) % 30

z = input("Digite o dia da semana que voce ira viajar: ")

if (z == "Domingo"): 
    z = 0
if (z == "Segunda-feira"): 
    z = 1
if (z == "Terca-feira"): 
    z = 2    
if (z == "Quarta-feira"): 
    z = 3    
if (z == "Quinta-feira"): 
    z = 4    
if (z == "Sexta-feira"): 
    z = 5    
if (z == "Sabado"): 
    z = 6

dia_semana_retorno = duracao_ferias % 7 + z
if (dia_semana_retorno > 6):
    dia_semana_retorno = (duracao_ferias % 7 + z) - 7

if (dia_semana_retorno == 0):
    dia_semana_retorno = "Domingo"
if (dia_semana_retorno == 1):
    dia_semana_retorno = "Segunda-feira"
if (dia_semana_retorno == 2):
    dia_semana_retorno = "Terca-feira"
if (dia_semana_retorno == 3):
    dia_semana_retorno = "Quarta-feira"
if (dia_semana_retorno == 4):
    dia_semana_retorno = "Quinta-feira"
if (dia_semana_retorno == 5):
    dia_semana_retorno = "Sexta-feira"
if (dia_semana_retorno == 6):
    dia_semana_retorno = "Sabado"

print("Voce voltara no dia",dia_retorno,dia_semana_retorno)
```